# Access to Hough Transform accumulator

Tags: emgucv

I'm trying to use the Hough Transform from EmguCV 3.0 to detect lines, but then, I'm only interested by some line "angles".
Basically, I just want to see almost 90/270º and 0/180º lines (with a margin of a few degrees). And of course, I just want those who reach a certain treshold.
I was thinking finding those lines using the accumulator and only looking at some  angles values (85 to 95º for instance)... but no way to access to this accumulator :/
Is there some smart way to do it? Or should I look at angles of the top lines from the Hough Transform and then just keeping the ones I'm interested in...?

Thanks =)

Comment: The only way to find those angles is after the computation has completed, unless you want to reimplement the Hough transform code.

Comment: What are you doing this for, though? Sometimes, there's a more robust or simpler way. For example, if you're trying to find whether there's a stronger vertical or horizontal pattern, you can use a Fourier transform.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer =) Actually, I'm trying to detect some characteristics in observed digits (on a board, with a camera, could be poor quality ...). Most of the time, it will be 7-segment digits, but not every time..., and I was experiencing different approachs. Generally, I can find straight segments (horizontal or vertical), and I wanted to exclude the diagonal ones. I haven't though of the Fourier Transform for that purpose: Can you tell me more about this one? Thanks!

Comment: So for that, I wouldn't use a Fourier transform, but there are tutorials for digit and character recognition. First, find the region in the image that contains the characters you're looking for. Then, break it up by character and use the character recognition. Easier said than done, but you should be able to find some online tutorials.

Comment: Yeah, I applied some of them actually, and it is working quite fine :) But I wanted to try different approaches, so I will probably try something with the accumulator from the Hough Transform (or just looking at the angle of the outputs lines =) ). Thanks for your help !